# same controller name in different modules in zf2

Tags: rest, zend-framework2

I just disvovered today that zf2 doesn't realy like when 2 controllers have the same name even if they are not in the same module.
However, I need to be able to call
localhost/users/types
and
localhost/messages/types

For the moment, my two controllers have the same names.
I also discovered that whatever the name of the module is, I always get the result of messages/types, even with localhost/nonexistingmodule/types oO

Here is what my module.config.php looks like :

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokales' => array(
            'messages' => 'Messages\Controller\MessagesController,
            'messages' => 'Messages\Controller\TypesController,
        ),
    ),
    'di' => array(
        'instance' => array(
            'alias' = array(),
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes => array(
            'restful' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment'
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/Messages/:controller[.:formatter][/:id],
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'module' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'formater' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'module' => 'Messages',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array( ... ),
);
```

I have tried to set 'module' => 'Messages' in constraints (we never know :p) but I had a 404 error.
The module.config.php of the Tasks module is the same but for tasks.
I originaly had aliases but I removed them after I read somewhere this was not very recomanded.

One more thing, this is a REST API, all my controllers extends AbstractRestfulController (in case this is important)

Anyone has an idea of how to make my 2 url to work?

Thanks :)

Comment: Every controller must have a **unique** name not only in its module, but also among **all** modules. Also, as you could have guessed by yourself, it makes no sense at all to write an array with the same key defined twice, the second definition will simply override the first.

Comment: I tried to rename my controllers so they have different name and so, I changed the invokables (ex : 'types' => 'Tasks\Controller\TasksTypesController') as I want them to be accessible with the "same route" id localhost/messages/types and localhost/tasks/types. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases for invokables or services and anything else should be unique. If they are not unique they may be overwritten by another module in the order the modules themselfes are loaded. That means: when setting up invokables or any sorts of aliases, make sure that the aliases are **unique** and **meaningful**. Personally i name my Controllers like this:

```
'invokables' => array(
    'mymodule-controller-controllername' => 'Mymodule\Controller\ControllernameController'
)
```

Same with Services or any other sorts of aliases

```
'services' => array(
    'mymodule-service-servicename' => 'Mymodule\Service\Classname'
)
```

The Documentation follows a Namespace-styled syntax like...

```
'invokables' => array(
    'Mymodule\Controller\Controllername' => 'Mymodule\Controller\ControllernameController'
)
```

...which personally i find totally confusing, as it resembles a Namespace way too much and doesn't really auto-imply that it is just an alias / key

Now your comments-question i do not understand. You want to match **one route** to **two different controllers**? That would be impossible and senseless.

**Answer Update with routing config**

As for routing configuration you have several possible ways. Personally i put lots of effort into building up literal routes, since they are the fastest, but also require a lot of manual attention. Alternatively there is segment routes which inhibit a little more magic to them. I will cover the literal approach for you:

**Module Messages**

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'messages-controller-index' => 'Messages\Controller\IndexController',
    )
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'messages' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/messages',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'messages-controller-index',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                )
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'types' => array(
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/types',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'types'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**Module Tasks**

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'tasks-controller-index' => 'Tasks\Controller\IndexController',
    )
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'tasks' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/tasks',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'tasks-controller-index',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                )
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'types' => array(
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/types',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'types'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

So what's happening there is:

- if route is `/messages` if routes to controller-alias `messages-controller-index` with `indexAction()`
- if route is `/messages/types` it stays at controller-alias `messages-controller-index` but goes to `typesAction()`
- if route is `/tasks` if routes to controller-alias `tasks-controller-index` with `indexAction()`
- if route is `/tasks/types` it stays at controller-alias `tasks-controller-index` but goes to `typesAction()`

You could obviously change controller aliases and meanings behind that. If you'd want to add an ID for a route like `/messages/types/1` you'd build a child-route to the types-route that is of type `segment` and check for an [:id] parameter whose constraints should be numeric :) Check the official ZF2 Manual for more information, i'm lazy now :P

Comment: Well, it was not very clear indeed, by route, I mean the same end on the url. So, you confirm that it is not possible to have localhost/tasks/types and localhost/messages/types pointing to 2 different controllers in 2 different modules ?

Comment: Nono, that, of course, is absolutely possible. I will now add my answer according to your needs ;) Gimme a minute

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explaination :)

Comment: "...which personally i find totally confusing, as it resembles a Namespace way too much and doesn't really auto-imply that it is just an alias / key". I totally agree with.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Make sure you have a `__NAMESPACE__` default in your route definition, and then make sure all your service names are prefixed with it. Usually, the value will match your module namespace.

For the longer explanation:

I'm going to be blunt: it's a really bad practice to have a dynamic segment in your route that maps to the controller (`:controller` in your example). The reason is that if somebody discovers this, they can do controller injection, and request a controller that should not be routed by this particular route.

Additionally, the practice can easily lead to collisions, particularly if you omit a `__NAMESPACE__` default in your route configuration -- which, based on the question, you've already discovered.